# How to fix venn diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, venn-diagrams

I would like to make a venn diagram with Tikz, but instead of labeling A, B or C each circle I'd like to give some other names. However, having read the manual I've changed their labels but each new word doesn't fit in each shape.

My code so far is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelA={υλικά}, labelB={καταναλωτικά}, labelC={διαρκή}, labelABC={ΑΑΑΒΒΒΨΨΦΦΔ}]
\fillACapBCapC
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

My diagram I'd like to be like:
[image]

How can I change how big a circle can be?

Comment: In the manual there is a `radius` option that might be of help (beware: I never used that package). Did you have a try with it?

Comment: You have also to set `overlap=...` if you set `radius=`

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino Just today I've found it, because I wanted to make a diagram like this. In a few minutes I'll upload what I'd like to make.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Here a quick sketch with only tikz (without venndiagram) - if you dont need any other functionality of the package maybe this does suffice.
Removed the greek text as I dont have those packages installed here.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw(4,3)circle(5 and 3)node(A){Text A};
\draw(8,6)circle(5 and 3)node(B){Text B};
\draw(10,2.5)circle(5 and 3)node(C){Text C};
\begin{scope}
\clip(4,3)circle(5 and 3);
\clip(8,6)circle(5 and 3);
\clip(10,2.5)circle(5 and 3);
\filldraw[yellow!80](0,0)rectangle(10,10);
\end{scope}
\node at ($0.33*(A)+0.33*(B)+0.33*(C)$){Text M};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]