# Tikz and Venn Diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, venn-diagrams

I'm trying to draw a Venn diagram for the intersection of {A n B n C} using tikz. Where A: politician, B: lying, C: wicked.

Here's what I have so far but I can't sort the shading out! Any help would be great!

```
\def\firstcircle{(90:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\secondcircle{(210:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
  \def\thirdcircle{(330:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}
    \clip \firstcircle \secondcircle;
    \fill[cyan] \thirdcircle;
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}
    \clip \thirdcircle \secondcircle;
    \fill[cyan] \firstcircle;
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}
    \clip \thirdcircle \firstcircle \secondcircle;
    \fill[cyan] \secondcircle;
      \end{scope}
      \draw \firstcircle node[text=black,above] {$Politician$};
      \draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] {$Lying$};
      \draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] {$Wicked$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Failed Venn]

On a side note, if anyone has any good documents on learning tikz please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: For learning materials, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz  (And an unrelated note: Don't write `$Wicked$`, just `Wicked`. If you need italics, use `\textit{Wicked}`.)

Comment: Is http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124571/36296 what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yay! Perfect! I'll delete this post?

Comment: See also http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/

Comment: Also just realised that I have formalised the inference incorrectly: should be $\exists x (Px \& Qx \& Wx)$.